# Append data from SELECT to existing table

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm trying to append data fetched from a SELECT to another existing table but I keep getting the following error:

**Provided Schema does not match Table *projectId*:*datasetId*.*existingTable***

Here is my request body:

```
{'projectId': projectId,
 'configuration': {
     'query': {
         'query': query,
         'destinationTable': {
             'projectId': projectId,
                 'datasetId': datasetId,
                 'tableId': tableId
         },
         'writeDisposition': "WRITE_APPEND"
     }
  }
}
```

Seems like the *writeDisposition* option does not get evaluated.

Answer (score 1):

In order for the append to work, the schema of the existing table must match exactly the schema of the query results you're appending. Can you verify that this is the case (one way to check this would be to save this query as a table and compare the schema with the table you are appending to).

Comment: Yep it's exactly the same schema indeed. Have you ever tried yourself? I'm willing to know if it ever works for someone.

Comment: Hi I'm trying to append a table to another table with the same Schema, the only thing different is the order of fields are different. It gave me the same error `Provided Schema does not match Table projectId:*datasetId*.existingTable`

Answer (score 1):

Ok think I got something here. That's a weird one...
Actually it does not work if you have the same schema exactly (field mode).

Here is the source table schema:

```
 "schema": {
   "fields": [
   {
     "name": "ID_CLIENT",
     "type": "INTEGER",
     "mode": "NULLABLE"
   },
   {
     "name": "IDENTITE",
     "type": "STRING",
     "mode": "NULLABLE"
   }
  ]
  }
```

If if I use the copy functionality from the browser interface (bigquery.cloud.google.com), I get the exact same schema which is expected:

```
"schema": {
  "fields": [
  {
    "name": "ID_CLIENT",
    "type": "INTEGER",
    "mode": "NULLABLE"
  },
  {
    "name": "IDENTITE",
    "type": "STRING",
    "mode": "NULLABLE"
  }
  ]
 }
```

But then I cannot append from the following fetch to the copied table:

```
SELECT ID_CLIENT + 1 AS ID_CLIENT, RIGHT(IDENTITE,12) AS IDENTITE FROM datasetid.client
```

although it returns the same schema, at least from the browser interface view, internally this returns the following schema:

```
"schema": {
 "fields": [
 {
   "name": "ID_CLIENT",
   "type": "INTEGER",
   "mode": "REQUIRED"
 },
 {
   "name": "IDENTITE",
   "type": "STRING",
   "mode": "NULLABLE"
 }
]
```

}

Which isn't the same schema exactly (check mode).

And weirder this select:

```
SELECT ID_CLIENT, IDENTITE FROM datasetid.client
```

returns this schema:

```
"schema": {
  "fields": [
  {
    "name": "ID_CLIENT",
    "type": "INTEGER",
    "mode": "REQUIRED"
  },
  {
    "name": "IDENTITE",
    "type": "STRING",
    "mode": "REQUIRED"
  }
 ]
}
```

Conclusion:

Don't rely on tables schema information from the browser interface, always use Tables.get API.
Copy doesn't really work as expected...

Comment: My question is how can you append data from a SELECT since you cannot force the fetched result schema's fields mode?

Comment: 1. How was the original table created? Via a load / import operation?  2. What is it about table copy that doesn't work as expected?
3. If you have a brand new table, and run two identical queries with write_append, does that work?

Comment: 1. The original table was created with the bq commandline tool mk -t command then bq load operation
2. Sorry I didn't mean table copy (my bad) but more the Jobs.insert API functionality with the writeDisposition option set to 'WRITE_APPEND'
3. If you mean to create a brand new table from a SELECT and then run this SELECT again, yes this appends properly. The problem is that you have to always run the same query since the schema that is deduced from your fetch seems unpredictable.

Comment: For the 3rd point I mean that the schema.field.mode seems unpredictable

Comment: The unpredictability of the mode of the returned values is a bug, we should fix it or make covariant schema evolution work. There is a hack-y workaround to force the result to be nullable: `SELECT if (True, ID_CLIENT, INTEGER(null)) as ID_CLIENT FROM datasetid.client`

Answer (score 1):

I have successfully appended data to existing table from a CSV file using bq command line tool. The only difference i see here is the configuration to have

**write_disposition** instead of writeDisposition as shown in the original question.

What i did is add the append flag to bq command line utility (python scripts) for load and it worked like charm.

I have to update the bq.py with the following.

1. Added a new flag called --append for load function
2. in the _Load class under RunWithArgs checked to see if append was set if so set 'write_disposition' = 'WRITE_APPEND'

The code is changed for bq.py as follows

In the `__init__` function for `_Load` Class add the following

```
**flags.DEFINE_boolean(
        'append', False,
        'If true then data is appended to the existing table',
        flag_values=fv)**
```

And in the function `RunWithArgs` for `_Load` class after the following statement

```
if self.replace:
      opts['write_disposition'] = 'WRITE_TRUNCATE'
```

---> Add the following text

```
**if self.append:
      opts['write_disposition'] = 'WRITE_APPEND'**
```

Now in the command line

```
> bq.py --append=true <mydataset>.<existingtable> <filename>.gz
```

will append the contents of compressed (gzipped) csv file to the existing table.