# Append query results to a table

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm having some problems right now when I try to insert a query job via the API that will append the results of the query to another table.  Looking at the docs this seems to be possible by inserting a query job, setting the destination table, and setting the writeDisposition to 'WRITE_APPEND'-- like so:

```
{  
  "configuration": 
    {
      "query": 
        {
          "query": "SELECT item_id, seller_id, event_type, quant_sold, amount, event_date, total_sale_amount, unique_transaction_id FROM [OUR-DATASET-ID.OTHER-TABLE-ID] WHERE unique_transaction_id NOT IN (SELECT unique_transaction_id from [OUR-DATASET-ID.OUR-TABLE-ID])",
          "destinationTable": 
            {
              "datasetId": "OUR-DATASET-ID",
              "projectId": "OUR-PROJECT-ID",
              "tableId": "OUR-TABLE-ID"
            },
          "createDisposition": "CREATE_IF_NEEDED",
          "writeDisposition": "WRITE_APPEND",
          "preserveNulls": false
        }
    }
}
```

However, this doesn't work.  No data is appended to the destinationTable, even though I've verified that the query in question does in fact return results.  I've tried the same job via the API Explorer on the BigQuery docs page with no luck.  It does however work if I run the query via the BigQuery UI, and select the destination table from the Enable Options menu.  Is there something I am doing wrong here?  I saw [Append data from SELECT to existing table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10536472/append-data-from-select-to-existing-table) which was left mostly unanswered.  Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Can you provide a job id of a job that should have appended results to a table?

Comment: Here's one: job_553d7f9c6dbf42bfbd5ac06e66ce8800

Comment: I'm sorry I think there might be a mistake in my testing-- I just tried doing a query and appending via the UI again and this time it gave me a message that I cannot refer to the destinationTable in the query.  I'm doing a subquery on the destinationTable, so I'll eliminate that.  If the problem still persists after I fix the query I will give another update.

Comment: OK ... we probably should allow self-modification of tables. I'll file an internal feature request bug.