# Bigquery: How to preserve REPEATED attribute when appending query results to a table

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a BQ Table where one of the columns is a REPEATED type and I'm trying, using Python client libraries within Google App Engine, to create a new table with some of the columns recalculated and a couple more columns added.

Using the configuration below, the copy does work but the `arguments` column (the REPEATED column in the source table) gets flattened into multiple rows. *How do I preserve the REPEATED-ness of the column?* We know it's possible because Web UI can do it, but I can't find any documentation on how to do it with the Python client library.

```
query_sql = """
SELECT _id,app_name,user,source,function,arguments,startT,deltaT,ip_addr,location,session,agent FROM 
  (select _id, app_name,user,'server' as source, function,arguments,startT,deltaT,ip_addr,'eng.example.com' as location,session,agent from [probe_data.mini_probe_data] 
      where app_name = 'smeng' 
      and user is not null 
      and not function contains 'ajax'), 
  (select _id, app_name,user,'browser' as source,function,arguments,startT,deltaT,ip_addr,'eng.example.com' as location,session,agent from [probe_data.mini_probe_data] 
      where app_name = 'smeng' 
      and user is not null 
      and function contains 'ajax'),
"""
jobData = {
    "projectId": project_id,
    "configuration": {
        "query": {
            "query": query_sql,
            "destinationTable": {
                "projectId": project_id,
                "datasetId": dataset_id,
                "tableId": tbl_dst,
            },
            "createDisposition": "CREATE_IF_NEEDED",
            "writeDisposition": "WRITE_APPEND",
        }
    }
}
```

For clarification, `writeDisposition` needs to be `WRITE_APPEND` because I'll be combining data from multiple tables, but that's for later, when this part is working.

I have read most of the documentation on copying as well as transforming BigQuery tables via a client API, for example on [managing tables](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/tables) and [this SO discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19104598/append-query-results-to-a-table), among others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you need to add flattenResults: False to make sure results of query are not flattened.

From the documentation:

> jobs[].configuration.query.flattenResults
>
> boolean
>
> [Optional]
> Flattens all nested and repeated fields in the query results. The
> default value is true. allowLargeResults must be true if this is set
> to false.